# Java exit code: 137 and nothing printed

Tags: java, jvm, exit-code

My code below is supposed to print the int 'numComb'. However, it does not. When I run it, nothing happens until I stop the program and then the correct answer appears with 'exit code: 137'. I have read that 137 means it could be an issue with the JVM. However, I also know it can be a result of other things so i would like to know the cause of it in my code and if it has anything to do with it not printing the answer. Could that be the JVM error. Thank you, Sam.

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int o = 0;
        int numRem = 0;
        int numLim = 0;
        while((sc.hasNextInt())&&(o<1)) {
            int numT = sc.nextInt();
            numLim = sc.nextInt();
            numRem = sc.nextInt();
            o++;
        }
        List<Integer> persons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int nextPer;
        while(sc.hasNextInt()){
            nextPer = sc.nextInt();
            if(nextPer<=numLim) {
                persons.add(nextPer);
            }
        }
        int ns = persons.size();

        int numComb = (factorial(ns)) / ((factorial(numRem)) * (factorial(ns - numRem)));//replace with '1' in reply to comment
        System.out.println(numComb);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static int factorial(int n) {
        int f = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            f *= i;
        }
        return f;
    }
```

This is the whole program because I was requested for it in a comment. Also, my test input was :

```
3 2 2 1 2 3
```

Comment: My assumptions is that your scanner is using up all of your system resources some way or another...

Comment: Interesting, what do you think is causing this.

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out which line(s) it stops at, and this is probably exclusive to your machine.

Comment: It fails after line 2, 3, 4 on the above code. I will try adding a hasnextInt() method.

Comment: that didn't work when I tried to add an if statement to check for next int to each of line 2, 3 ,4.

Comment: Does it works normal without `factorial` method (i.e. placing constant value instead of it)?. Because I suspend that it recursive and can make stack overflow

Comment: Nope, even when I make numComb=1, it still fails and has exit code 137. It does this when i set break point just after code I mentioned in edit.

Comment: Strange, as I tried I never got such error/exception (I placed value 4 instead of that method). I relapsed the code with new one but again it works. Can you provide full (with main) but minimal code with inputs when you are running, when it throws?

Comment: There you go, comment is in there.

Comment: Yes, thank you for update. I ran it and it still work!!!. But one issue: when I printing numbers it still request new ones, so I typed letter to stop input. And after it I get number result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're error may be here:

```
    int o = 0;
    int numRem = 0;
    int numLim = 0;
    while((sc.hasNextInt())&&(o<1)) {
  ----> int numT = sc.nextInt();  // You are re-declaring numT
        numLim = sc.nextInt();
        numRem = sc.nextInt();
        o++;
    }
```

You can avoid coding errors like this by adding more white space, where appropriate.

For example, I would have written your code in this format:

```
int o =         0;
int numRem =    0;
int numLim =    0;

while( sc.hasNextInt() && (o < 1) )
{
    int numT =  sc.nextInt();
    numLim =    sc.nextInt();
    numRem =    sc.nextInt();

    o++;
}
```

By following a coding style / guideline it will not only make it easier for yourself to read the code but others as well.

Comment: I tried declaring it externally and just modifying it but it gives the same result.

Comment: What I am saying is that you do not need it.  The `sc.nextInt()` is assigning the number to a variable that is next used.  I imagine this will change the way the program would operate. My input for `3 2 2 1 2 3` resulted in `numLine` == 2, instead of 3.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. I am sorry, but could you try explaining what I could do and why it could work.

Comment: Try commenting out the line `int numT = sc.nextInt();`, or just remove it if it will not be used.  What you are doing is adding one of the values in the `3 2 2 1 2 3` sequence to the `numT` variable, then it is never used.

Comment: Even if it is not used, I need it to be discarded though because the following ints have they own meaning as you can see in my code. Also, thanks for the tip. I have taken it onboard. :)

Comment: Aha, I have fixed it by just performing two if statements for each and then a fro loop with ifs later on for nextPer.